# Unable to change privacy settings upon install of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: gnome, 18.04, settings, gnome-shell, privacy

I am new to Linux with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS as of this morning.

Anyone else experienced the inability to change privacy settings upon installation? I.e. I can tap the toggle switch to the "off" position for "automatically empty trash" but the toggle immediately bounces back to the "on" position. This is the same for all other privacy settings. I have Gnome Shell 3.28.2

Comment: This is not normal, but I do not know what's the cause the problem. I have the same setup but have not experienced your problem.

Comment: Please remove the solution part and post it to the answers section below by clicking "answer your own question" button. It's completely fine to answer your own question :)

Answer (score 1):

Removing config files and clearing the cache by running the following commands fixed the issue

```
cd ~
rm -r .cache .config
```

---

<sub>Source: [added as an update to the question by OP](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1057379/5) (which should have been posted as an answer instead)</sub>